# C# set desktop path for database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have created a project in visual studio, that uses a database to store and retrieve details.

I want to deliver an executable and just let the user know that he has to place the database file on the desktop.

if i do
`String myDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);`

it looks like i cant set the database position after like this:

`using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = myDesktop\Database1.sdf))`

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Form a correct path using the Path.Combine method of the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string conString = "Data Source=" + Path.Combine(myDesktop, "Database1.sdf;");
using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
```